# Prove $a^3+b^3+c^3\ge a^2+b^2+c^2$ if $ab+bc+ca\le 3abc$

Tags: inequality

> if $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers and $ab+bc+ca\le 3abc$ Prove:$$a^3+b^3+c^3\ge a^2+b^2+c^2$$
>
> Additional info:I'm looking for solutions and hint that using Cauchy-Schwarz and AM-GM because I have background in them.

*Things I have done so far:* We are given $ab+bc+ca\le 3abc$ So$$2(ab+bc+ca)\le 6abc$$

so I can rewrite question as$$a^3+b^3+c^3+6abc \ge (a+b+c)^2$$

Also We can say$$9a^2b^2c^2 \ge (ab+bc+ca)^2 \ge 3abc(a+b+c)$$

My problem is is finding a way to use this facts and change the form of inequality to apply AM-GM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First
$$3abc\ge ab+bc+ca\ge 3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}.$$
So $abc\ge 1$.
It's then follows that $$a+b+c\ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc}\ge 3.$$
Now 
$$3(a^3+b^3+c^3)\ge (a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)$$
by Rearrangement Inequality or by
$$(a+b+c)(a^3+b^3+c^3)\ge (a^2+b^2+c^2)^2\ge (a^2+b^2+c^2)\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}.$$

Comment: thanks for posting your solution.I just have problem figuring out what you done there $3(a^3+b^3+c^3)\ge (a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)$.would you please explain it?

Comment: It follows from the equality which is two consecutive applications of Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: now i got your idea.you Proved that $(a^3+b^3+c^3)\ge (a^2+b^2+c^2)\frac{(a+b+c)}{3}$ is true. also you shown that $\frac{(a+b+c)}{3} \ge 1$.so $(a^3+b^3+c^3)\ge (a^2+b^2+c^2)$ is true

Answer (score 0):

We only need to show that
$$(bc+ca+ab)(a^3+b^3+c^3)\ge3abc(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$
which is equivalent to
$$\sum_\text{cyc}a(b^4+c^4-b^3c-bc^3)\ge0$$
or
$$\sum_\text{cyc}a(b-c)^2(b^2+bc+c^2)\ge0$$
where $\sum_\text{cyc}$ is a summing operator $\sum_\text{cyc}f(a,b,c)=f(a,b,c)+f(b,c,a)+f(c,a,b)$.